# Can I manage another computer in over an Internet connection?

Tags: remote-desktop

I bought my mother an iMac. In order to maintain my tenuous grip on sanity, I would like to be able to manage this machine from my home office using my own Mac. I have a Cox cable connection, she has a Verizon wired connection.

Is this possible with Apple Remote Desktop or similar?

Comment: I agree with jherran if you also have a Mac. If not, I'd look at [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)

Comment: ARD is harder to punch through a firewall than Messages or TeamViewer, both of which are 'looking out' rather than 'drilling in'. ARD also costs 80 bucks, US.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has tools for that in Sharing.

I personally am a fan of the app called [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?pid=google.tv_mac.s.us&gclid=CIHOk_G-m8MCFUmUfgoduFkAAA) and use it with my family and extend family and friends in Europe as well.

It is no so much Sharing but taking the control and fixing stuff remotly, or just watching them do something as a teacher.

It can be set to auto start with mac so you can access any time without need for the other party do to anything.

It of curse offers Audio/Video chat or messaging while in session, but I mostly use that to tell the other party to stop moving the mouse around and just watch me fix they problem :)

Comment: Notice no-one ever mentions LogMeIn any more, since they started charging for it?  ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I hate websites that do not show how much (after free trial) and you have to log in to find out.

Comment: Me too. I used LogMeIn for years until they changed to the 'rental' version, then I just let my membership lapse. Remoting is not really a technology you can 'rent' to people [certainly not occasional home users] when the free alternatives are perfectly good for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the Messages app. The last release have a feature for that. You can select a contact and tap on Details. It will appear a new window where you can locate the following icons.

[image]

Click the first one and will see and option to Invite to share or Ask to share screen.

[image]

If you ask to share, you will be able to voice chat and control you mom's screen.

Comment: I can't create an Apple ID for my supportee, she does not have a credit card.

Comment: AppleID without a credit card - http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034

Comment: You might even consider [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) after that. You could even set her up as a Parental Control account if you really want to reign in what she does ;)

Comment: I don't want to create an Apple ID for my supportee. This person will never remember the password and it just becomes another support issue for me.

Comment: Then it's looking like TeamViewer. Set & forget. & free. It sounds like a similar task I used to use LogMeIn for, 'parental-control-in-reverse'. TeamViewer is the go-to, since LogMeIn started charging.